# Stored Procedure - Search Parameter across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following query that does the job just fine, but I'm wondering whether there is a better way to be doing it inside the `WHERE` clause.

Any comments/feedback on improving it would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    C.ClientID, 
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName as FullName, 
    C.DOB,
    G.Gender, 
    G.GenderIcon, 
    C.VerificationCode, 
    MAX(V.StartDate) as LastVisitDate
FROM 
    Client C
LEFT JOIN 
    Visit V ON C.ClientID = V.ClientID
INNER JOIN 
    Gender G ON C.GenderID = G.GenderID
WHERE
    (FirstName like '%' + @Criteria + '%' or
     LastName like '%' + @Criteria + '%' or
     VerificationCode like '%' + @Criteria + '%')
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert why not writing this as an answer... there is no more answers for this question!!

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, appreciate your reply. As Hadi said, feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There may be other answers, but you're right, it shouldn't be a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than looking into things like full-text searching, no. If one column is vastly more likely to contain the matches than the others and you have covering indexes, you could use three queries and run them separately, but given the columns you return they likely all involve table scans anyway. You may also consider querying for `LIKE @Criteria + '%'` first, since that can use an index to support an efficient range scan (more efficient than reading all rows, in any case). None of this improves the worst case, though.

Comment: I think you meant Index Range Scan. Since the '%' wildcard will do a range-scan. A seek looks for a fixed and known value, whereas `%` could have / match multiple endings for the `@Criteria`.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: if there is an index on the column, an index seek operator will be used to jump to the first row in the range. The remainder is scanned, you're quite right about that, but this is distinct from an actual index scan operator. I guess this is a question of terminology -- I'm using the names the engine itself uses.

Comment: Actually, to be very precise, what it generates is a *logical* index seek operator that uses a physical index scan... it's not particularly clear. I'll amend my answer so there's no confusion about what I mean.